# CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert CFOptionFlags Not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I have a CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert setup like this:

```
CFOptionFlags cfRes;

            CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert(5, kCFUserNotificationNoteAlertLevel,
                                           NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                           CFSTR("Okay"),
                                           CFSTR("Stop!"),
                                           &cfRes);

            switch (cfRes)
            {
                case kCFUserNotificationDefaultResponse:
                    strTest = CFSTR("Default response");
                    break;
                case kCFUserNotificationAlternateResponse:
                    strTest = CFSTR("Alternate response");
                    break;
            }
```

With this code I get this error:
**use of undeclared identifier kCFUserNotifactationDefualtResponce**  (And the other kCF*'s)
Any ideas? I have the following imported:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: The CFUserNotification API is not available on iOS.  Looks to me like you copied that bit of code from a Mac App.

Comment: Ahhh ok. The UIAlertView code works but the switch doesnt. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Ahh never mind. I got it to work with a switch. Thanks!

Comment: The CFSTR("Okay") expression yields the following warning for me: warning: type-punning to incomplete type might break strict-aliasing rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The CFUserNotification API is not available on iOS. Looks to me like you copied that bit of code from a Mac App.

*Quoted from [CodaFi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049642/cfusernotificationdisplayalert-cfoptionflags-not-working#comment22902155_16049642) above so question can be marked as answered as per: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments*